# Native base extend theme not fully applying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

i'm trying to change the `outline` variant of Native Base's `Button` component. I want it to have a border color the same as the text color.

I have a theme.ts file with this

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Button: {
      variants: {
        outline: ({ colorScheme }: any) => {
          return {
            borderColor: `${colorScheme}.500`,
          };
        },
      },
      baseStyle: {
        _text: {
          fontWeight: 800,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

And this is my App.tsx

```
export default function App() {
  const { Navigator, Screen } = createNativeStackNavigator();
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ContextProvider>
        <NativeBaseProvider theme={theme}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Navigator
              initialRouteName="Login"
              screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
            >
              <Screen name="Login" component={Auth}></Screen>
              <Screen name="Register" component={Register}></Screen>
            </Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
      </ContextProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

The `fontWeight` of the `baseStyle` is getting applied, but the border color is not changing at all. I tried to change other properties and apparently only the `_text` is changing.